# Stovetop is making the GFCI outlet trip when I try and light the stove

Tags: electrical

My stovetop is throwing the GFCI outlet when I turn the igniter on. The igniter doesn't make the clicking sound.

Comment: Is this in the US? If so, is this a stove with gas fired cooktop and electric oven in one unit? What mfgr and model?

Comment: Yes, what make and model is your stovetop?

Answer (score 2):

Use a (long) lighter or a match to light the top burners until you can get the igniter unit replaced. Your symptoms indicate that it has a sufficient ground fault to trigger the GFCI.

Comment: Don't most spark igniters arc to ground? Should such an appliance even be on a GFCI?

Comment: The high-voltage **secondary** of the igniter **transformer** sparks to ground. There should be **no** connection from the secondary/spark electrode side of the module to line or neutral - that's the **primary side** of the transformer. So, a properly functioning spark ignitor should not affect a properly wired GFCI (and in this case, it's evident that it used to work, and now doesn't, though that is *not* expicitly stated.) Lower voltage is made into current-limited high voltage so that the spark will jump the gap. It's not a matter of applying 120V to the spark electrodes directly.